# How to inspect PostScript fonts (.pfb files)?

Tags: fonts, applications

What application (possibly command-line oriented) can I use on a macOS Sierra to inspect PostScript fonts (`.pfb` files) in a similar manner to how Font Book can be used to inspect, say, OpenType fonts (`.otf` files). I'm interested in such details as the font's family (=typeface) name, and the glyph layout table (i.e. what glyph is associated with every code point (="slot" number)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/). Can also be installed with Homebrew.

Comment: You should mark your own answer as correct by using the checkmark next to the answer if this satisfied your question